# how to extract this code using vba - i need to click on next button

Tags: html, excel, vba

Just an FYI... I am using `UserForm1.WebBrowser1.document.CurrentWindow.execScript("return doSubmit( this.form )").Click` code to extract

I need to click on next button but element ID is not available; below is the HTML code

```
<input class="saveButton" onclick="return doSubmit( this.form )" type="BUTTON" value="Next">
```

i tried using below vba code but this does'nt work for me

```
Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy: Set CurrentWindow = UserForm1.WebBrowser1.document.parentWindow
```

`Call CurrentWindow.execScript("return doSubmit( this.form )")`

Please let me know if any further thing required

Answer (score 0):

So. Clicking something without an ID can be done, you just have to know how to FIND what you're looking for. Normally, I'd recommend clicking on the element by innertext as a good backup.

I know you can't probably share the webpage, so I won't ask. But, what is the tag assigned to this element? "td","a","div","input" etc etc.

You can finding the element using this loop.

```
Dim Cnt As Variant
Dim oCell As Object
Cnt = 0  ' 
With oie.document.all
For Each oCell In .tags("a")  'This will change according to html tagging of element
    If oCell.value = "Next" Then 'If this "Next" value is unique. 
        oie.document.all.Item(cnt).click 'If doesn't trigger try nextline
        oie.document.all.item(cnt).fireevent ("onclick") 
    Exit For
    End If
Cnt = Cnt + 1
Next oCell
End With
Set oCell = Nothing
```

Now, in order to get this to work. Enable the "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference library.

A couple things that might have to change depending on the HTML structure.

1. oie.document.all.item 'This might change to something like oie.document.body. or oie.document.forms(0).document.all.
2. Like I said, the "a" needs to be changed to look at every tag assigned to the element in the html.

   I hope this points you in the right direction, if you don't want to run the loop everytime the macro runs, you can put this into a function that runs and assigns all of the elements on load. But one thing at a time :)

Comment: i am using userform to perform this task. As you said, we need some unique value so i have 'savebutton' as class and change in code as 'oCell.class'... Is there any chance to find the 'savebutton' as this is unique?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks for your quick turn around!

Code is not running...

I tried your code as per my requirement and make the necessary changes:

```
Dim Cnt As Variant
Dim oCell As Object
Cnt = 0
With UserForm1.WebBrowser1.document.all
For Each oCell In .tags("input")  
If oCell.Class= "saveButton" Then
UserForm1.WebBrowser1.document.all.Item(Cnt).Click
UserForm1.WebBrowser1.document.all.Item(Cnt).FireEvent ("onclick")
Exit For
End If
Cnt = Cnt + 1
Next oCell
End With
Set oCell = Nothing
End Function
```

Just an FYI... i am using userform to perform this task.
As you said, we need some unique value so i have 'savebutton' as class and change in code as 'oCell.class'...
Is there any chance to find the 'savebutton' as this is unique?

Thanks a ton!